# While to check something in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if I have an hour in the database but If I have more than hour in the database it outputs twice, if I have 3 three times...

In this specific case this gives me: 9 (in blue color) and then 9 (in red color)

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM consulta
                  WHERE professional=1
                  AND client=0');
                              
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

if ($row['hora']=='09:00:00') { echo '<p class="blue">9</p>'; } 
else { echo '<p class="red">9</p>'; }

}
```

I have a MySql database with columns: id, professional and hour. I have stored 2 hours and this is what I get if I echo `$row['hora'] 09:00:00 and 10:00:00`

In this case the if should give me just 9 in blue because it is in the database. I do not understand why it happens. How can I solve this?

This is the structure of the MySql database:
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that your code print in both cases: True and False??

Comment: Yes, this is how you say

Comment: Show your table structure, and the data type for the hora field(muéstrame al tipo de dato del campo hora y como lo almacenas en la tabla)

Comment: If you have 2 rows, you will have 2 results, and 3 will give you 3. If you are only wanting 1 result, either change your query to only select 1 row, or just remove the `else{}` block.

Comment: @Robert: the hora is type time

Comment: In the if, for testing purposes, put a var_dump($row['hora']); and show the results

Comment: @Robert I am not sure If I understand. If I echo $row['hora'].',' or If I put $hora=$row['hora'].','; echo $hora;  it gives me: 9:00:00,10:00:00

Comment: Why do I have a negative point? what should I do better?

Comment: If someone gives a negative point should explain why to be able to correct  or improve here or next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are building up a calendar or the like.

The query you are using is returning all rows (and you are looping over each row, regardless of the hour). If you want to check if specific hours exist you could build up an array of hours:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM consulta
                  WHERE professional=1
                  AND client=0');
$hours = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $hours[$row['hora']] = $row;
}
```

Now to check a specific hour we can do:

```
if (!empty($hours['09:00:00'])) { 
    echo '<p class="blue">9</p>'; 
}else { 
    echo '<p class="red">9</p>';
}
```

Edit: Explanation

In the first loop we are building up an array. This will look like:

```
$hours = array(
    '08:00:00' => $dataForThisRow,
    '09:00:00' => $dataForThisRow
);
```

In the above `'08:00:00'` is called a `key`. Each key is a time that was found in the database.

To check if there is an entry in the database for our time we can check if there is a non empty key. Hence we use:

```
if(!empty($hours['09:00:00'])
```

This `if` will run if `$hours` has a `key` with the value `'09:00:00'`. If there is no key then the other part of the `if` will run.

Comment: Yes I am building like a calendar. $hours = array()l gives me error in the editor ?

Comment: @Nrc That was a typo. Fixed now

Comment: The output gives me an error: Array to string conversion

Comment: @Nrc The only thing being output in my example is strings. What line is the error on?

Comment: Your code works if I check 9:00:00 because it is in the database. But if I check anything else like 09:30:00 if gives me an error in if ($hours['09:30:00']) {

Comment: Can you explain your code, please?

Comment: @Nrc I've updated the code so empty results don't produce an error. I'll add an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Your code seems to work. I do not understand very well. Are you converting $row['hora'] in a array?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49166/discussion-between-jim-and-nrc)

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql query like below:

```
    $query = "SELECT TIME_FORMAT(hora,'%H:%i:%S') FROM consulta
                  WHERE professional=1
                  AND client=0";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: This gives me an error in the code editor.

Comment: I edit my answer and I replace single quotes `'` with double quotes `"` ;) thanks for your comment.

Comment: Now it gives me an error in the output:Notice: Undefined index: hora. Anyway, I am not sure but I think the time format is not the problem?

Comment: @Nrc You can try to experiment with your problem. If you try to variable dumping your result with command `var_dump($result)` you see that the index name is now `TIME_FORMAT(hora,'%H:%i:%S')` to correct this without change your code, you can change sql query with this addition `SELECT TIME_FORMAT(hora,'%H:%i:%S') as hora FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing with this value: 09:00:00, but the database seems to have stored this other: 9:00:00

Comment: In the database i have type time so it gives me 09:00:00. Sorry I write it wrong here. I updated